# Android: wmv format is supported by some devices

Tags: android, video, format, wmv

Why is the wmv video format supported by some android devices and not supported by others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the decoder present on the devices. WMV is a Microsoft proprietory format for which you need license from them.

Answer (score 0):

wmv video format is not officially supported by Android. See the list of supported media formats [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core)